# Fatal error: Call to undefined function random_bytes() error

Tags: php

I have built a password reset system and used random_bytes but it is throwing back the error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function random_bytes()

```
$selector = bin2hex(random_bytes(8));
$token = random_bytes(32);
```

I am expecting it to create the information and then progress through the script but I am getting the error instead. Does anyone know how I can get this to work? My server is PHP 7 compatible.

Comment: what is the php version you are using ?

Comment: Just updated the question. I am using PHP 7

Comment: Are you absolutely sure?

Comment: its core php, but only from 7+ so are you really really sure your using php7+ ? can you post the results from `phpinfo();`

Comment: I am also going to be trying to apply this system to one on 5.6 so I might just use 5.6 instead - do you know what I can use within 5.6?

Comment: <7 https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Comment: Here's a good article with links: https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/07/how-safely-generate-random-strings-and-integers-in-php

Comment: try `echo bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(12)); `

Comment: @tim I have just run it and PHP Version 7.1.27 came back

Comment: odd cant explain that, did you install this? or are you on some kind of 'host' ask them perhaps.

Comment: `random_bytes` is part of the `CSPRNG` extension : check that this extension is loaded in your PHP configuration (`php.ini` or `print_r(get_loaded_extensions());`)